# Special Schengen visa requirements for non-EU citizens residing in Ireland?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, ireland

I am a citizen of Kazakhstan, but I work and live in Ireland. I have IRP (Irish Residence Permit) with Stamp 1 and my de-facto partner has IRP with Stamp 3.

If I apply for Schengen visa from here, i.e. to the Embassy of Greece in Ireland, will they check the dates of validity of my IRP? Particularly, can they issue a visa for a period beyond my Irish Residence Permit? The thing is that IRP needs to be reissued every year and I think I will have a vacation just at the time when one IRP expires and another one starts.

The official website of The Embassy of Greece in Ireland doesn't say anything about IRP and the support just sends the link to the website. At the same time, people say that it may be asked, because the Embassy needs to be sure that I have legal ground to return to Ireland after my vacation.

Comment: Nevermind, sorry for the poor research of the question. I have just actually found a document, will post an answer now for other people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This document](https://www.mfa.gr/missionsabroad/images/visas/missions/ireland/Ireland_List_of_supporting_documents_En.pdf) on the official website of The Embassy of Greece in Ireland says that I  need to have:

> Irish re-entry (multi) visa and/or Irish Certificate of Registration (GNIB card)
>   valid for at least 3 months beyond the intended departure from the Schengen area